# Is 'spreading' a gerund or participle in "Some of other guests tried to damage Margaret's good reputation by spreading false statements"?

Tags: gerunds, participles

> Some of other guests tried to damage Margaret's good reputation by **spreading** false statements.

In this sentence is 'spreading' a gerund or participle modifying statements.

Comment: If the ing-form follows after a preposition (in this case "by") it is clearly a gerund.

Comment: Oops then sorry for spreading false information. I'll need to refresh my memory.

Comment: I don't know what a gerund is, I don't know what a participle is, never mind the difference between them. However, "attempted" or "endeavored" would be better than "tried" here; and there's no need for "good," either: someone's reputation is stellar and impeccable and top-notch by definition unless otherwise specified or sarcastically implied.

Answer (score 1):

> Some guests attempted to damage Margaret's reputation by spreading false statements.

"Spreading "is a gerund (used with a preposition "by").
But you can also use a participle.

> Some guests attempted to damage Margaret's reputation spreading false information.